# how to write an array into an XLSX sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, arrays, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

```
def save_data():
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    print(entryArray)
    for b in range(len(entryArray)):
        temp = entryArray[b]
        wb.cell(row=b+1, column=1).value = temp
    wb.save('/home/'+getpass.getuser()+'/Desktop/FileName.xlsx')
```

i get the error message

```
  File "C:/Users/thoma/ownCloud/Computer Science/Project/Psudo code/1.2/Project 404.py", line 292, in <module>
    save_data()
  File "C:/Users/thoma/ownCloud/Computer Science/Project/Psudo code/1.2/Project 404.py", line 258, in save_data
    wb.cell(row=b+1, column=1).value = temp
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'cell'
```

this is the value of entryArray:
['58578', '876', '66', '98', '807', '78907', '90', '078907', '8967', '760', '658', '467', '58346', '54', '65', '785', '896', '9-08', '-980', '456', '456', '09', '87', '89', '765', '765', '765', '765']

how do I create an XLSX sheet then write these values into it using openpyxl. the XLSX sheet does not exist I need to create it during the functions running.

thanks in advance

Comment: `openpyxl` uses Excel's terms. Workbook is the entire file. *Sheets* are what you write into. A workbook can have many sheets. When you create a new Excel file you get 3 sheets named `Sheet 1` etc. You can even rename them. The same terms are used in `openpyxl`. And there are no arrays, there are *ranges* that may contain 1 or more row, 1 or more columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing your cells from `workbook` which does not have `cell` attribute. What you should access before then is the `worksheet` object. You can do that via:

```
ws = wb.active
```

So a simple fix is to add the code above right after your `wb = ...`; and change the `wb` to `ws` within your loop. This will give you a local excel file with your data in the first column:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Prove that:

```
r=entryArray.shape

for i in range(r[0]):

    for j in range(r[1]):

        ws.cell(row=i+2, column=j+1).value = entryArray[i][j]
```